# How to split string data and load data in table using PySpark

Tags: string, pyspark

What are the total number of events?

Example data:

```
FWD,29052016:09:01,10.56| FWD,29052016:10:53,11.23| FWD,29052016:15:40,23.20
```

Comment: I am looking it in pyspark

Comment: String data means single-line fo string separated by | or a csv with multi line

Comment: text file with multiple string which is separated by |

Comment: I need to understand it more, string separated by `|` contains rows|rows or columns|columns

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `sep` (separator) parameter and set it to `|`:

```
data = spark.read.csv([DATA_PATH], inferSchema = True, header = True, sep = "|")
```

Comment: Can i use multiple sep = "|" parameter while importing. Because i want to separate data (,) as well

Comment: Nope. You have two separators ?! 
The best thing to do here is to replace the `|` by `,` with a shell script : 
`sed -i 's/|/,/g' your_file.csv`
Explanations : https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands